# Elastic Search - Filter value by latest date

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, subquery

In elastic search we have a document with different values. Each value have a period. A period tells if the value is still actual, and tells in what period the value is actual.

Example bellow:

```
"": [
{
  "memberType": user,
  "period": {
    "validFrom": "1964-08-23",
    "validTo": "2008-12-31"
  },
},
{
  "memberType": admin,
  "period": {
    "validFrom": "2008-12-31",
    "validTo": null
  } 
}
]
```

In our query, I want to filter by memberType. But only deal with the newest type of member. So if I filter by memberType "user", the document above should not be a match, because the actual memberType is admin.

In the above example, I could filter with a boolean filter by memberType, and *missing* field on the validTo field.

But if the person is not valid longer at all, both will have a validTo date defined, and I have to look at the newest date then.

How can I achieve that? I'm thinking of a nested query, or a custom script filter. But I dont know how to express the query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your field name for this array is *memberDetails*, you can use this query to achieve what you need.

```
{
    "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
    "filter" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "memberDetails",
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "term" : {"memberType" : "user"}
                        },
                        {
                            "missing" : { "field" : "validTo" }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal. 

But your answer is not complete. The given example only return, if the field "validTo" is missing. But that field is not missing in all cases, some cases the validTo will have a date value, and I need to find the newest date. Example.:

    "": [
    {
        "memberType": user,
        "period": {
        "validFrom": "1964-08-23",
        "validTo": "2008-12-31"
      },
    },
    {
        "memberType": admin,
        "period": {
        "validFrom": "2008-12-31",
        "validTo": "2012-04-30"
      } 
    }
]